# Cygwin - компиляция без зависимости от cygwin

Tags: cygwin, компиляция

Параметр компилятора `-mno-cygwin` больше не работает.

Я пытался использовать `-static` (однажды, вроде, это работало), но компилятор не может найти установленную `-lpng`

Сейчас попытался сменить компилятор на mingw. Все так же не находит при попытке использовать -static. Файлы в lib есть.

Comment: Почему с `-static` не работает? Если файлы есть и линкер их не находит, то пути к ним линкеру не известны, что еще может быть.